# How to Train FCN network with 6 channel input images?

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation

Input image is 6 channels and I am using FCN-8 and I am changing the First conv layer like this:

```
model = torchfcn.models.FCN8sAtOnce(n_class=2)
model.conv1_1 = nn.Conv2d(6, 64, 3, padding=100)
```

It throws an error,

```
 RuntimeError: shape '[1, 1664, 1024, 1]' is invalid for input of size 1650000
```

But When I keep it by default at 3 channels and give 3 channel image it works fine:

```
model = torchfcn.models.FCN8sAtOnce(n_class=2)
model.conv1_1 = nn.Conv2d(**3**, 64, 3, padding=100)
```

This model is being imported from torch so I don't really know how to debug it.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

**or**

basically I want a segmentation network which can take more than 3 channel as an Input, please share the link if available.